# Jquery: Change class on different ul li section

Tags: jquery, indexing

**Description:** I have code such as follows.  I have labeled them with their correct indexes.  I understand that the first ul tag is index 0, the second is index 1.  I understand that the li is index 0 - 5 in each of the ul's.  I have these set as buttons so when you click on them it removes a CSS class and then adds another CSS class.  However due to scope if I click on the first-child in the second UL (or index 1 UL as labeled below) I cannot change the class of the first UL (Index 0 UL) last-child by using next() or prev().

**Question:** If I click on Index 0 LI (in Index 1 UL) how do I change the class of Index 5 LI and/or Index 4 LI of the Index 0 UL?

```
<ul> (Index 0 UL>)
<li><li> (Index 0 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 1 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 2 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 3 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 4 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 5 LI>)
</ul>
<ul> (Index 1 UL>)
<li><li> (Index 0 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 1 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 2 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 3 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 4 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 5 LI>)
</ul>
<ul> (Index 2 UL>)
<li><li> (Index 0 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 1 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 2 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 3 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 4 LI>)
<li><li> (Index 5 LI>)
</ul>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Wayne

Comment: possibly shorten your question

Comment: questions that ramble on with lots of meaningless text and no code don't get much attention around here. Put relevant code in your question, few will go to your site to try to sort out what's what

Comment: I will shorten it however perhaps the website should change its suggestions when posting.  They told me to be as detailed as possible and provide as much information as possible.

Comment: +1 for shortening your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use these plugin methods:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
    nextSiblingOrCousin: function() {
        var $next = this.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) {
            $next = this.parent().next().children(':first');
        }
        return $next;
    },

    prevSiblingOrCousin: function() {
        var $prev = this.prev();
        if ($prev.length == 0) {
            $prev = this.parent().prev().children(':last');
        }
        return $prev;
    }
});
```

With these, you can just change all your calls to `.prev()` and `.next()` to `.prevSiblingOrCousin()` and `.nextSiblingOrCousin()`.

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99gFC/2/)

Note: Previously I thought you had a `<div>` around each `<ul>`, but I see that you don't.

Comment: I was planning on putting divs around them so that I can use the animation option.  The jsfiddle works.  I didn't see that you updated your answer.  I am going to try it out.  Thank you for the update on the code.  This will probably save me from having to do what I was trying.  Thanks.

Comment: This works perfectly. I have a lot to learn about jquery. I had no idea that you could extend jquery and frankly don't know exactly what that means 100%. I am presuming it means that you can make your own functions and replace core functions like prev() and next() but at this time would have no clue how to write that on my own. Thank you for that.

Comment: @scrfix - I'm glad it works for you. It got late last night, so I didn't take the time to improve my answer and do the jsfiddle until this morning. In case you want to learn about extending jQuery, you should first know that `jQuery.fn` is just an alias for `jQuery.prototype`. A "prototype" property is a JavaScript thing, not a jQuery thing. Start by reading up on JavaScript prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.  It appears that parent().prev() will allow me to talk to the previous parent and

parent().prev().find('li:last-child') will allow me to talk to the last child.  There is also something I read in the wiki called nth-last-child-type (or similar) that will allow me to talk to any number of elements within the previous parent starting from the last one and counting down.

Wayne

```
       if($(this).index()<2) { // Only do this if the button clicked on is indexed at 0 or 1
          if($(this).parent().index()!=0) { // Ensure we are not at the first parent index
            if(!$(this).parent().prev().find('li:last-child').hasClass('whatever')) { // Look for the correct class 
              alert("Current Index: "+$(this).parent().index());
              alert("Previous Parent Index: "+$(this).parent().prev().index());
              alert("Previous Index Last Child: "+$(this).parent().prev().find('li:last-child').index());
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: What I did here will work but the solution John put out there is much better and a lot easier.